# Unable to display image on Crystal Reports from SQL Server - C# application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports

A C# application browses a picture from a file and uploads it into the sql server 2005 database as byte[]. When the table is opened (using management studio) it is shown that the picture field reads "Binary data". When the application runs, every other field from the same table is shown on the report except the picture field. On the database, the type of the picture field is image. On the crystal report the picture is blob field. The image is not displayed on crystal report. I am using a dataset. Your assistance is highly appreciated!

---

@ C_Major, what part of code you want to see? I used the wizard to create a crystal report using the dataset. The dataset is based on the view I created in the DB and there is a report manager dialog box with a combo box filled with the list of names saved earlier. User selectes the name from the combo and enters a show report button. Then the following code will executes.

```
    void studyreport()
    {
        DataTable dtindividual = register.studyreport(cmbName.Text);
        DataTable dtfetchpic = register.fetchpic(cmbName.Text);

        byte[] MyData = new byte[0];

        DataRow myRow;
        myRow = dtfetchpic.Rows[0];

        MyData = (byte[])myRow["Picture"];

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(MyData);

        individual.SetDataSource(dtindividual);

        reportviewer.viewer.ReportSource = individual;
        reportviewer.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Please post some blocks of code(what & how you have achieved it). It will be helpful for identification of issue.

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: What kind of image you're displaying? JPG, PNG, BMP, any other? It is quite possible that Crystal Reports just can't handle some image types. My only experience was with one signature pad, which could generate jpeg structure (which was displayed properly) or raw bitmap data (which wasn't displayed at all). Field type (image vs varbinary(max)) didn't matter for Crystal Reports.

Comment: @Arvo- I was tring to display JPEG image.

Answer (score 0):

If you can just make the image uploaded to the database, and call that field to the report, it may not output anything to you while making it but will give you image in preview, upload the image, any type and just call it to the report using the field.

To be more explicit, you can convert any image to binary sequence, store in db and later on call the field to report, it will display you the actual image you converted to binary earlier,

Comment: What do you mean by 'image in preview'? I have uploaded the pic to the database in binary. On the crystal report wizard, I added relevant fields from the dataset. Every field is visible on the report except the picture. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: this may be odd to you, but em asking that when you click and drag the Picture Field from the Field Explorer, does the box appear ? with nothing in it? an empty box on report? but if you preview the report you will see the image, even when you run the report you will still see the image, but not when you are putting it on the report. I am sorry if I say something wihch is not making sense. thanks

Comment: @ Waqar Thanks for replying. I understand what you're saying. When I click and drag the pic field, box apperars with nothing in it. yes, an empty box. When previewing and running it, empty box will appear. When I add a new crystal report to my project, a crystal report gallery dialog appears. when choosing a 'choosing a report wizard' radio, it will show you a standered report creation wizard and in it with available datasources. I chose the view that I have created from the database. To your surprise, it will show me the fields of that view and there is no picture field in it.  What can I do?

Comment: okay, now, the table which contains the image, have you made that field available in the view? if yes, just like you drag and drop the image or a field from field explorer, exactly the same way drag and drop the picture field from the view or table and drop it on the report. again I am sorry if I say anything which doesn't make sense. :)